# List iteration on Android, foreach or indexed

Tags: java, android, performance

Given a `List<T>`, which is the preferred way to iterate on **Android**? Are there any performance differences on a modern day Android device?

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    T element = list.get(i);
    ...
}
```

or

```
for (T element : list) {
    ...
}
```

Edit: This question is specific to the Android runtime. The other "duplicate" question doesn't address the Android specifics.

Comment: the first version is slightly slower

Comment: @Blackbelt There is no way the first version is slower when written correctly (size should be saved in a variable so its not called N times).  The second requires a function call to iterate so it will always be slower.  Its just a matter of it the cost is enough anyone should care (probably not).

Comment: First first one is slower if the List is a LinkedList

Comment: This question is Android specific, I disagree that it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The second version -- the for-each loop -- allocates an `Iterator` object, which can be undesirable for Android code.  The first version may be preferable, as long as you're sure the `List` is a `RandomAccess` implementation such as `ArrayList`.